# How displaye Spark result in GUI (Tkinter)

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, tkinter

I selected different files(.csv .json .txt ...) using SPARK,then ingested them into HADOOP(HDFS).That's work,but when i associate this function to a button for that the result will be displayed in a GUI i get:
the function is executed in terminal and the GUI doesn't displayed.
How i can fix that.
This is the code:

```
def classifyCSV():
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("SparkByExamples.com") \
        .getOrCreate()
    df = spark.read.csv("... /file3.csv")
    df.printSchema()
    df.show()
    df.write.save('hdfs://localhost:9000/mydata/csv', format='parquet',mode='append'
button1 = Button(gui1,text="Press for csv file" , commande=classifyCSV)
button1.place(x=120 , y=235)
```

NOTE:
each file has its function

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Spark isn't running in the GUI, it's in the background and meant to be distributed on a cluster.

If you want to display anything, you need to `collect()` the dataframe to the active Spark driver, then you should create some Table or List widget in Tkinter to populate that list into, since printing the schema and `show()` only goes to the terminal

If you have a Dataset small enough to process and display on one machine's GUI, you probably shouldn't be using Spark, though

Comment: Then when i'll use collect() it will be displayed throught the GUI ? (Note: I should use Spark and GUI, this is recommended for my project)

Comment: No, you need to store that list in a Tkinter widget, as stated